# How to use Ansible wait_for to check a command status with multiple lines?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Ansible v2.4.0.0

I'm installing Gitlab-CE where I run the following in an Ansible task. As you can see, some of the processes are down, but they eventually come up.

```
# gitlab-ctl status
run: gitlab-workhorse: 0s, normally up
run: logrotate: 1s, normally up
down: nginx: 0s, normally up
down: postgresql: 1s, normally up
run: redis: 0s, normally up
run: sidekiq: 0s, normally up
run: unicorn: 0s, normally up
```

How can I write an Ansible wait_for task to check when all the services are in the run state? IOW I only want to proceed to the next task when I see this

```
# gitlab-ctl status
run: gitlab-workhorse: 0s, normally up
run: logrotate: 1s, normally up
run: nginx: 0s, normally up
run: postgresql: 1s, normally up
run: redis: 0s, normally up
run: sidekiq: 0s, normally up
run: unicorn: 0s, normally up
```

Comment: "*How to use Ansible wait_for to check a command status with multiple lines?*" -- how would you use wait_for to check a command status with a single line?

Comment: @techraf, see answer

Comment: What do you mean by "see answer"? The answer does not mention `wait_for` module.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use `retries`/`until` method:

```
- command: gitlab-ctl status
  register: cmd_res
  retries: 5
  until: cmd_res.stdout_lines | reject('search','^run') | list | count == 0
```

We drop any line from output that starts with `run` and count them. Proceed to the next task only when there are no such lines left.

Comment: Thanks. Can I put a delay between retries, say delay: 1?

Comment: Please, check documentation for `delay` option: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#do-until-loops

Comment: TL;DR- Yes, you can use `delay: 1` to put a delay between retries. The default values for `retries` is `3` and `delay` is `5`.